# Getting an R dplyr data frame to output all on one line in a file created in the bash line

Tags: r, bash, dplyr

Sorry if this is a basic question - I have looked for an answer to this but can't find one (possibly because I do not know how to word it correctly).

I am executing an R script using the following command:

```
Rscript --vanilla script.R inputfile.csv &> log_file.txt
```

One of the outputs to this `log_file.txt` is a dplyr dataframe, however it splits the sixth and seventh column into different lines, like this:

```
   col1       col2    col3      col4      col5   col6
  (dbl)     (fctr)   (dbl)     (dbl)    (fctr) (fctr)
1     4      rt227 9998440 1.011e-23      rt66  2e-65
2    NA                 NA        NA       dd7  3e-12
                                  col7
                                (fctr)
1                                heart
2                            Uric acid
```

When really I want it to look like this:

```
   col1       col2    col3      col4      col5   col6        col7
  (dbl)     (fctr)   (dbl)     (dbl)    (fctr) (fctr)      (fctr)
1     4      rt227 9998440 1.011e-23      rt66  2e-65       heart
2    NA                 NA        NA       dd7  3e-12   Uric acid
```

Note that at the top of the script I am running:

```
options(dplyr.width = Inf)
options(dplyr.print_max = Inf)
```

Is there some kind of setting in dplyr that controls this or is it the Bash line that's the problem?

Comment: That looks like the regular `options('width')`. dplyr.width doesn't allow multiple rows of columns like that